Why is C=C bond length in methoxyethene greater than nitroethene
Why is C=C bond length in methoxyethene greater than nitroethene?
I have come across this question while studying  resonance and mesomeric effect in organic chemistry. Since both the afore-mentioned compounds have resonating structures with both +M effect as well as -I effect, which effect do we consider while comparing?
*M : mesomeric effect
*I : iductive effect

See the mesomeric effect. In nitroethene, the resonating structure containing C=N has a very small contribution to the hybrid

I find it amazing that so far nobody has given any values for the relevant bond lengths, along with supporting references.
